# how to print a string from dynamically allocated arrays at a given position

Tags: c

I want to use the function to print one string of a given position from keybord, in the exact order as they are in the array but changing the other chars to null. 
The problem is that the first loop of the function won't even execute and I have no idea why.

-ex: first output:

```
e il cie                       enta traspare   e
```

-and by passing to the function a=2, i want to get output like:

```
cie //and the rest of the chars must be '\0'


char no_words(char *sentence, int a)
{
  int count=0,i,len;
  char lastC;
  len=strlen(sentence);

  if(len > 0)
  {
    lastC = sentence[0];
  }
  for(i=0; i<=len; i++)
  {
    if((sentence[i]==' ' || sentence[i]=='\0') && lastC != ' ')
    {
      count++;
    }
    lastC = sentence[i];

    if(a!=count-1){
      sentence[i] = '\0';
      printf("%c", sentence[i]);
    }else
      printf("%c", sentence[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

//function that divides my text

```
char fun(char *tab, char warunek){

int i,l=0;
l = strlen(tab);
i=0;
char poczatek;


while(i<l){


do{
    if(tab[i] == '\n'){
        printf("\n");
    }

    if(*(tab+i) == warunek && i< l){

        do{

            printf("%c", *(tab+i));
            ++i;

        }while (*(tab+i) != warunek && i < l);
        printf("%c", *(tab+i));

    }

    *(tab+i) = '\0';
    printf("%c", *(tab+i));
    ++i;


}while (*(tab+i) != warunek && i < l);


}
*(tab+l)= '\0';




return 0;
```

}

//in main

```
int main(){

char **array = NULL;
int i,j;
char line[100];  
int line_count=0;
int line_lenght=0;
int a;
char warunek;
int l=0;
int *lenght;
char **arr2 =NULL;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("tekst1.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("blad otwarcia pliku!");
    exit -1;
}

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp) != NULL){ 
    line_count++;
}

rewind(fp);


array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * line_count); 
if (array == NULL){
    return 0;
}


for (i=0; i<line_count; i++){

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp); //szczytuje po 1 linii

    line_lenght = strlen(line);


    array[i] = malloc(line_lenght +1); //+1 for null


    strcpy(array[i], line);

}

for (i=0; i<line_count; i++){
    printf("%s", array[i]);
}

printf("\nenter position\n");
scanf(" %d", &a);
printf("\nenter condition\n");
scanf(" %c", &warunek);
printf("\n\n");





for (j=0; j<line_count; j++){

        *(*(array)+j) = fun(*(array+j) , warunek);

}



for (j=0; j<line_count; j++){

    *(*(array)+j)=print_nth_word(*(array+j),a);
    printf("\n");

}



 return 0;
```

}

Comment: In `printf("%s\n",*(a));` , `*a` is a `char` not a string.

Comment: What compiler and warning level are you using that does not complain about `printf("%s\n",*(a));`?

Comment: Am I right, that you need to print n-th word from a sentence, where `n` is entered by user?

Comment: Do you really want to *print* null characters?  That can certainly be done, but I suspect you misunderstood.  If you set (at least) the *one* character after your wanted substring to a null character, then that makes it pretty easy to print just the substring (and zero null characters) -- if I were to speculate wildly, I might guess that that's what you're actually expected to do.

Comment: Also, do you know about the `strtok()` function?  If you are permitted to use that then it may make your job much easier.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov that's correct, that's what  no_words(char *sentence, int a) function should be doing

Answer (score 0):

```c
void print_nth_word (const char *sentence, int n) {
    int word_no = 0;
    char ch, lch = ' ';

    while (ch = *sentence++) {
        if (ch == ' ' || word_no != n) printf ("%c", '.');
        else printf ("%c", ch);

        if (ch == ' ' && lch != ' ') word_no++;
        lch = ch;
    }
}
```

I replaced `'\0'` with `'.'` to make results visible.

Invocation:

```
print_nth_word ("e il cie                       enta traspare   e", i)
```

Output:

```
.....cie........................................
```

Comment: That works, but when I call this function in main after a function that divides the text -> char fun(char *tab, char condition); like this: 
    for (j=0; j<line_count; j++){

            *(*(array)+j) = fun(*(array+j) , condition);

    } and later on                                                                                                     
  for (j=0; j<line_count; j++){

        *(*(array)+j)=print_nth_word(*(array+j),a);
        printf("\n");

    } it won't print anything

Comment: Probably your dividing logic is wrong.  Could you add its code to original question?

Comment: What does it mean? What can I change in main function? Thank you!